# Symfony 4.3 Mailer - undefined method named "getAll" of class "Symfony\Component\Mime\Header\Headers"

Tags: php, symfony, mailer

I'm trying to send mails with the [new mailer component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html) in symfony 4.3 but if i try my implemetation, i'm getting this exception:

**Attempted to call an undefined method named "getAll" of class "Symfony\Component\Mime\Header\Headers".**

stack trace:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException:
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getAll" of class "Symfony\Component\Mime\Header\Headers".

  at vendor/symfony/mailer/DelayedSmtpEnvelope.php:76
  at Symfony\Component\Mailer\DelayedSmtpEnvelope::getRecipientsFromHeaders(object(Headers))
     (vendor/symfony/mailer/DelayedSmtpEnvelope.php:69)
  at Symfony\Component\Mailer\DelayedSmtpEnvelope->getRecipients()
     (vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/AbstractTransport.php:75)
  at Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\AbstractTransport->send(object(Email), object(DelayedSmtpEnvelope))
     (vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/SmtpTransport.php:115)
  at Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport->send(object(Email), null)
     (vendor/symfony/mailer/Mailer.php:38)
  at Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer->send(object(Email))
     (src/Controller/TicketController.php:209)
  at App\Controller\TicketController->sendEmail('example@mail.com', 'example@mail.com', null)
     (src/Controller/TicketController.php:193)
  at App\Controller\TicketController->handleRequest(object(Request))
     (src/Controller/TicketController.php:51)
  at App\Controller\TicketController->createGeneral(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:198)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (index.php/:25)
```

My Code so far:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;

class TicketController extends AbstractController
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    // ...

    public function sendEmail($ticketRecipient, $responsibilityRecipient)
    {
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from('exampleSender@mail.com')
            ->to($ticketRecipient, $responsibilityRecipient)
            ->subject('example subject')
            ->text('example text')
            ->html('<p>todo Twig Integration<p/>');

        try {
            $this->mailer->send($email);
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?